Laravel 7 query whereBetween 2 month
I want to find data between 2 month, for example data between months 8 and 9.
Edit: The issue is in this line
else if ($bulan1 != "semua" && $bulan2 != "semua") {
   $query->whereBetween(DB::raw('MONTH(kred_kep_aktf_kompetensi.mulai)'), [8, 9]);
}

And this is the full code of the function
public function load_kompetensi(Request $request) {
        $jenis_kegiatan = $request->input('jenis_kegiatan');
        $bulan1 = $request->input('bulan1', 'semua');
        $bulan2 = $request->input('bulan2', 'semua');
        $tahun = $request->input('tahun', 'semua');
        $unit = $request->input('unit', 'semua');

        try {
            $query = DB::connection('database')
                ->table('kred_kep_aktf_kompetensi')
                ->join('Karyawan', 'kred_kep_aktf_kompetensi.nid_karyawan', '=', 'Karyawan.NID')
                ->join('kred_jenis_kegiatan', 'kred_kep_aktf_kompetensi.id_jenis_kegiatan', '=', 'kred_jenis_kegiatan.id')
                ->join('kred_jenis_peran', 'kred_kep_aktf_kompetensi.id_peran', '=', 'kred_jenis_peran.id')
                ->select('kred_kep_aktf_kompetensi.*', 'Karyawan.Nama', 'kred_jenis_kegiatan.nama_kegiatan', 'kred_jenis_peran.nama_peran');

            if (session('jabatane') == "Pelaksana") {
                $query->where('kred_kep_aktf_kompetensi.nid_karyawan', session('nidkaryawan'));
            } else if (session('jabatane') == "Subag/Kanit") {
                $query->where('kred_kep_aktf_kompetensi.id_unit_kerja', session('unite_id'));
            }

            if ($unit != "semua") {
                $query->where('kred_kep_aktf_kompetensi.id_unit_kerja', $unit);
            }

            if ($jenis_kegiatan && $jenis_kegiatan != 'semua') {
                $query->where('kred_kep_aktf_kompetensi.id_jenis_kegiatan', $jenis_kegiatan);
            }


            if ($bulan1 != "semua" && $tahun != "semua") {
                $query->whereMonth('kred_kep_aktf_kompetensi.mulai', $bulan1)
                      ->whereYear('kred_kep_aktf_kompetensi.mulai', $tahun);
            } else if ($bulan1 != "semua" && $bulan2 == "semua") {
                $query->whereMonth('kred_kep_aktf_kompetensi.mulai', $bulan1);
            } else if ($bulan1 != "semua" && $bulan2 != "semua") {
                $query->whereBetween(DB::raw('MONTH(kred_kep_aktf_kompetensi.mulai)'), [$bulan1, $bulan2]);
            } else if ($tahun != "semua") {
                $query->whereYear('kred_kep_aktf_kompetensi.mulai', $tahun);
            }

            $files = $query->orderBy('kred_kep_aktf_kompetensi.id', 'asc')->get();

            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $file->mulai = Carbon::parse($file->mulai)->format('d-m-Y');
                $file->akhir = Carbon::parse($file->akhir)->format('d-m-Y');
            }

        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            throw $th;
        }

        return view("keperawatan.list_aktf_kompetensi_load", ['files' => $files]);
    }

And this is the format of kred_kep_aktf_kompetensi.mulai is (YYYY-MM-DD)
2024-08-09 06:51:30.000
What I have tried is making a query in SQL with the following query:
SELECT * FROM kred_kep_aktf_kompetensi
WHERE (MONTH(mulai) BETWEEN 8 AND 9);

and the result is same as what I want.
Thank you!
EDIT: I change the 8 and 9 in the issued code line with the request input. The type of bulan1 and bulan 2 is number

Can you please clarify your question ?Which sections of the query has issue or not working as per your expectation?

What is your DB? MySQL, MSSQL or something else?

@1stthomas MSSQL

what is your issue exactly? do you get an error or do you get something not matching with your expectation?

@FebryanAkhdani , I have posted my answer, please check and let me know your fedback

@FebryanAkhdani, another point to note that when you use this query $query->whereMonth('kred_kep_aktf_kompetensi.mulai', $bulan1); you are fetching record based on some string(i.e. $bulan1) where when you are using whereBetween in the query for the same column you matching against integer range i.e. [8,9] ,Here You only know what data type is for the mulai column.Please also check this point.

else if ($bulan1 != "semua" && $bulan2 != "semua") {
   $query->whereBetween(DB::raw('MONTH(kred_kep_aktf_kompetensi.mulai)'), [8, 9]);
}

The problem with above query is that Laravel's whereBetween() method expects the first argument to be a column name, not a raw SQL expression.
So instead try this approach with whereRaw.
else if ($bulan1 != "semua" && $bulan2 != "semua") {
       $query->whereRaw('MONTH(kred_kep_aktf_kompetensi.mulai) BETWEEN ? AND ?', [8, 9]);
    }

For more information about whereRaw check the docs-link here

It's all about the where clause and also the structure of your database tables. If you wanna use where between it required two values to set the range between them but keep in mind also the year for example if you have two rows with date like (2024-06-10 AND 2023-07-10) this will be included also inside your result. Better query maybe if you used DATE_SUB as MySQL function for something like this:
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tbl_name -> WHERE DATE_SUB(YOUR_DESIRED_DATE, INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= mulai

